# Optional compile in Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

Is there a way to tell Flash Builder 4.7 to optionally compile certain lines?

I.e. right now lets say an app has lines like:

```
if(DEBUGMODE) {
trace("foo");
}
```

Instead of it not displaying, I want it to not even compile that trace line (as bytecode) into the SWF/AIR/etc., and to toggle that across the whole app given certain directives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for conditional compiling, this link should help you: http://www.flexer.info/2010/03/04/how-to-create-conditional-compilation-definitions-conditional-compile-blocks/

Basically, you'll want to add `-define+=CONFIG::development,true` to your compiler options

Then, in your code, you'll create a conditional block like so:

```
CONFIG::development {
    // this is a conditional compile block
    // it will only compile if CONFIG::development is set to true in your options
}
```